# How to unbind solution from VSTS with missing binding info

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Somehow the binding between my project and VSTS disappeared.

Now, I get the following messages every time I open up my solution in Visual Studio.
[image]

[image]

But if I try to unbind the solution, there's not much I can do there -- see below:
[image]

At this point, I'd rather remove the binding -- if I can, create a new repo on VSTS and check in the solution as a fresh new solution.

How do I do that? How do I remove any traces of any prior link to a VSTS repo from my solution?

Comment: Did you click the "Bind" button to restore the binding?

Comment: That will try to restore the old bindings, won't it? I'm afraid that'll mess up my solution because I feel things went out of sync between my solution and the old repository. I'd rather simply remove any old references and check in my solution into a new repository as if it's a brand new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generally re-bind will restore the old bindings if you are in the old workspace.

Try below ways to solve the issue:

- Re-bind the solution (Click "Bind")
- Create a new workspace and get the latest version of sources, then
  open the solution to check if that works.
- Copy the solution to another folder, manually remove the Scc
  information from the solution (`*.sln`) and project file
  (`*.csproj`). Then open the copied solution and add the solution to
  the new repository (Add to source control). Reference below
  screenshot.

[image]